# A connected subset of the space of bounded sequences

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I found the following statement in an economics paper. It was stated as obvious, but I do not understand why it is obvious.

Definitions:

- $X$ is the topological space of all infinite sequences with elements in $[0,1]$, where the topology is induced by the supremum metric: $d((x_t),(y_t)) = \sup_t{(x_t-y_t)}$. (is this space called [$\ell^\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity)?).
- $D$ is the sub-space of $X$ which contains all the constant sequences: $D=\{(x,x,x...)|x\in[0,1]\}$.

The statement is:

> $D$ is connected.

And my question is: why?

Comment: In fact, it appears to be path-connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maps $x\mapsto (x, x, x, \ldots)$ and $(x, x, x, \ldots)\mapsto x$ are quite obviously onto and one to one from $[0,1]$ to $D$ and vice versa (the latter can be viewed as restriction of the projection of any component to $D$). Both are also easily seen to be continous, so you have a homeomorphism.

Alternatively, the set $\{(x, x, x, \ldots): x\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a one dimensional linear subspace of the vector space of real sequence, and $D$ is the intersection of that subspace with a closed sphere of radius $1/2$ centered at $(1/2, 1/2, 1/2, \ldots)$ in the given norm topology. Since both sets are convex their intersection is, too...)